# Django Multiple File Uploads

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I hope someone could help me with multiple file uploads. I have found some hints online but what I am struggling with is to display title and files on one page. Please see the code bellow to understand what I am trying to achieve:
models.py

```
class Uradna(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='files/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Uradna'
 
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

class Files(models.Model):
    tabula = models.ForeignKey(Uradna, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Files'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tabula.date)
```

views.py:

```
def homePageView(request):
    posts = Uradna.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
    context = {
       'posts':posts 
    }   
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)



def filesView(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Uradna, id=id)
    files = Files.objects.filter(tabula=post)
    return render(request, 'home.html', 
    {'post':post, 'files':files})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', homePageView, name='home'),
    path('<int:id>', filesView, name='home_files'),

]
```

home.html

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                         {{ post.date }}
                    </button>
                </h2>

            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="{{post.file.url}}" target="_blank">{{ post.title }}</a>                                     
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried another for loop from the foreign key but it obviously doesn't work since urls.py wants to redirect to the id page. If anyone could give me any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: what exactly you want to do? you have field name title in both models.. you also have ```filefield```for ```Uradna```. is this different file than ```files``` model?

Comment: Files model is a foreign key to Uradna so I can upload more files. The issue I have is that I want to have all the uploaded files shown under one common title as you can see in html. So when I upload one title with 3 files I want the to display on one page. I’ve no ide how to achieve that.

Comment: i have so old example multi file upload, you can read this https://github.com/idontgotit/upload-multi-file-django-angular